# Custom Layer in Keras - Dimension Problem

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to have a CNN which takes as an Input a Raw Signal and processes as first step the short time fourier transformation. Therefore I want to create a Custom Layer with Keras.

I Followed the explanation [here](https://gist.github.com/keunwoochoi/c9592922a17d71b745d47dc8eb7f0538#file-log_melspectrogram-py), and reduced the complexity to the following code:

```
class CreateSFTF(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32,n_fft=1000,hop_length=0,log=True, **kwargs):
      super(CreateSFTF, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.units = units
      self.n_fft = n_fft
      self.hop_length = hop_length
      self.log = log

    def build(self, input_shape):
      super(CreateSFTF, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
      def _tf_log10(x):
          numerator = tf.math.log(x)
          denominator = tf.math.log(tf.constant(10, dtype=numerator.dtype))
          return numerator / denominator

      stfts = tf.signal.stft(
          input,
          frame_length=self.n_fft,
          frame_step=self.hop_length,
          window_fn=tf.signal.hann_window,
          pad_end=False
      )
      mag_stfts = tf.abs(stfts)  
      return tf.expand_dims(mag_stfts, 3)

    def get_config(self):
      config = super(CreateSFTF, self).get_config()
      config.update({'units': self.units})
      return config
```

I Use the Layer here:

```
def DefineCNNWithFFTAtBeginning(length_signal):
  input = Input(shape = (length_signal,1))
  x = CreateSFTF(n_fft=1000,hop_length=100,log=True)(input)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x) # recommended

  x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid')(x)
  x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3),activation='relu', padding='valid')(x)
  x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(x)

  x = layers.Conv2D(16, (5, 5),activation='relu', padding='valid')(x)
  x = layers.Conv2D(4, (5, 5),activation='relu', padding='valid')(x)
  x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5))(x)
  x = Flatten()(x)

  x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

  x = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)

  model = Model(input, x)

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',            
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  model.summary()
  return model
```

I Call that here:

```
model = DefineCNNWithFFTAtBeginning(76000)
history =model.fit(X_train.values, y_train,
                            validation_data=(X_test.values, y_test),
                            epochs=50, batch_size=32,
                          shuffle = True)

Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 76000)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
create_sftf (CreateSFTF)     (None, 751, 513, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 751, 513, 1)       4         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 749, 511, 8)       80        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 747, 509, 8)       584       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 186, 127, 8)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 182, 123, 16)      3216      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 178, 119, 4)       1604      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 35, 23, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3220)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 3220)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 3221      
=================================================================
Total params: 8,709
Trainable params: 8,707
Non-trainable params: 2
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 987 samples, validate on 247 samples
Epoch 1/50
 32/987 [..............................] - ETA: 29s
```

the shape from the X_train is(xxxxx,76000)

**Old Error Message**

> Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but
>   got array with shape (987, 1) - **solved**

Does someone knows the solution? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

- Flatten was missing // sorry
- Pandas Dataframe ".values" did not provided the suitable input

**New Error Message**

> Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found tf.Tensor 'input_4:0' shape=(None, 76000) dtype=float32

Tried

- experimental_run_tf_function=False as parameter in Model.Compile -
  did not work
- If I exchange my Custom layer with x =
  Reshape(target_shape=(380,200,1))(input), it does work, **so the error must
  lie within the custom layer.**

Comment: Try with  input = Input(shape = (length_signal,))

Comment: Same Error Message

Answer (score 0):

The Input Layers adds a dimension for the batch size:

> Input shape
>
> nD tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., input_dim). The most common situation would be a 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim).

So, as the documentation of keras says (above quoted), you are specifying a batch size of `length_signal`.

Try something like `(length_signal, )`, `( ,length_signal)` (or simmmilar).

Comment: Also, you're saying at the model that the input laer will be of 76000 and your real input is 987.

Answer (score 0):

your model is expecting tensor of shape (None, 76000, 1) but you are passing (987,1)

you must preprocess your data to meet the criteria.

987 is not a valid dimension for this model you must use 76000 X 1. If it is not correct you must correct it in your model.

If you want to add extra dimension or training on single train data at a time you can extend the dimension using below code

```
x = np.random.randn((76000,1)) # shape = (76000 X 1)
x = x[None] # shape = (1 X 76000 X 1)
```

Comment: Yes, you were right, the Pandas Dataframe ".Values" function was not providing the suitable input - therefore I created a np.array which provides : (xxx, 76000) dimension.

Comment: run your code in python script not in Jupiter notebook. check whether this is working or not?

Comment: It does, but it stopps (I assume) at the backpropagation.

Comment: It is the one I mentioned under "new Error Message" : Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found tf.Tensor 'input_4:0' shape=(None, 76000) dtype=float32